# Why can't I ping an aws instance by public IP even though I can ping the private IP just fine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two instances (instance A and instance B) both are part of the same security group (say sg-1).

The security group has the following inbound rule set:

- Type: All traffic
- Protocol: All
- Port Range: All
- Source: sg-1

I can ping instance B from instance A using instance B's private IP but I get no response when I use instance B's public address.

What am i missing?

Edit:
If I change the source in the above security configuration to "Anywhere", ping to the public IP works.

Comment: Can you ping instance A using its public IP ? What OS are you running inside instances A and B? Have you checked the OS's firewall settings?

Comment: You mean ping instance A from instance A? I am running rancherOS on both. Dont think there are any OS firewalls active

Comment: [When you specify a security group as the source or destination for a rule, the rule affects all instances associated with the security group. Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses of the instances that are associated with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Comment: The public IP is mapped to the private IPs right?? So even if I ping a public IP, it should reach the instance with the corresponding private IP right? And since both instances are on the same security group, why would the ip matter?

Comment: Are the instances in the same subnet or different subnet?

Comment: The subnet IDs are the same. They are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be surprised only if you get no response when you ping instance B's `private` address.

Your subnet's routing table will route the public address to outside your VPC. When it goes out of the VPC and the traffic comes back in, **the source address will be the public IP (or NAT IP), not the private IP**. The routing table comes first before the security group. When you send traffic to another machine:

- The DNS name is resolved to an IP
- In your case you specify an IP, so no DNS resolution takes place
- If the address falls in one of the routing table rules, it will be routed accordingly
- When you specify the private IP, it is most likely routed internally and the security group allows the traffic and you are able to ping
- When you specify a public IP, it is most likely routed out. Without looking at the subnet routing table, it is hard to guess where the traffic goes. Show us the routing table and I can tell you what exactly is happening. **In this case, the source address will be public IP (or NAT IP), not the private IP**.
- Use `traceroute` or `lft` to track the network hops

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: The source address will be the public IP? What if A does not have a public IP? Having a public IP is the exception not the rule. It's not as simplistic as implied.

Comment: @RickO'Shea If A has no public IP then the only way it can reach a public IP is via NAT. The public IP visible at B's security group will be that of the NAT. If A has no public IP and no route through a NAT then all of its traffic destined to public IPs is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

The SG configuration like the one you mentioned, works only with private IP based communication.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules

> When you specify a security group as the source for a rule, traffic is allowed from the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group for the specified protocol and port. Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses of the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).